# ListView XAML show items multiple times c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, items

I'm working on a WIN 8.1 App. In my App I have a ListView where I'm binding a observable collection from a ViewModel. So far everything works fine. The Problem is, that in the Background all the Data will be loaded correctly, but my ListView displays after approximately 40 elements, from the beginning... In the Background the right Object is selected and 80 Objects are loaded.

Could it be a Problem with the Scrolling?

Does anyone know, how to solve this issue?

From an other Page, i navigate to the Page with the ListView:

```
private void ShowReturnData()
{
    ReturnViewModel retVM = new ReturnViewModel(_navigationService, SelectedTour);
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.ReturnPageKey, retVM);
}
```

In my ViewModel Constructor, I add my data to the observable Collection:

I'm working with MVVMlight.

Properties (ObservableCollection, SelectedItem):

--> observable Collection

```
/// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Data" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string DataPropertyName = "Data";

    private ObservableCollection<ReturnData> _myProperty = new ObservableCollection<ReturnData>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the Data property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ReturnData> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _myProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_myProperty == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _myProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(DataPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

--> SelectedItem

```
/// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedItem" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SelectedItemPropertyName = "SelectedItem";

    private ReturnData _selectedItem = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the SelectedTour property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public ReturnData SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_selectedItem != null)
            {
                _selectedItem.IsFirstItem = false;
                _selectedItem.IsLastItem = false;
            }

            _selectedItem = value;

            if (_selectedItem != null)
            {
                setIsFirstOrLastItem(Data.IndexOf(_selectedItem));
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedItemPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel Constructor:

```
public ReturnViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, TourDetailData tourDetails)
    {
        //Services
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        //Commands
        PrevPageCommand = new RelayCommand(GoToPrevPage);

        TourDetails = tourDetails;

        TourCustomerName = "Tour " + tourDetails.Tour + " > " + tourDetails.AccountName;


        Data = new ObservableCollection<ReturnData>(from i in TourDetails.ReturnData orderby Convert.ToInt32(i.ItemId) select i);


    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvItems" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ReturnDataTemplate}" 
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ReturnDataListViewItemStyle}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
            Margin="0,5,0,0" 
            Loaded="lvItems_Loaded">
        </ListView>
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ReturnDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="grid" d:DesignWidth="1344.53" d:DesignHeight="123.228">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <converter:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" Context="{Binding}" />
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="450*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="100" Fill="LightGray"  Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="100" Fill="LightGray"  Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <!--<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="100" Fill="LightGray"  Visibility="{Binding IsFirstItem, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="100" Fill="LightGray"  Visibility="{Binding IsLastItem, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>-->
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="{StaticResource OrangeHighlight}" Visibility="{Binding IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="42.667" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="{Binding ItemId}" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <!--<TextBox x:Name="tbxReturn" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="42.667"  Text="{Binding Return}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleValues}" PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus="True" DoubleTapped="tbxReturn_DoubleTapped" GotFocus="tbxReturn_GotFocus" />-->
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxReturn" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="42.667"  Text="{Binding Return}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleValues}" DoubleTapped="tbxReturn_DoubleTapped" GotFocus="tbxReturn_GotFocus" InputScope="CurrencyAmountAndSymbol" Foreground="#FF520164" />
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxMold" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Mildew}" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="42.667"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleValues}"   DoubleTapped="tbxMold_DoubleTapped" Tapped="tbxMold_Tapped" GotFocus="tbxMold_GotFocus" InputScope="CurrencyAmountAndSymbol" Foreground="#FF019E90" />
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxCredit" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Credit}" Grid.Column="4" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="42.667"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyleValues}" DoubleTapped="tbxCredit_DoubleTapped" Tapped="tbxCredit_Tapped" GotFocus="tbxCredit_GotFocus" InputScope="CurrencyAmountAndSymbol" Foreground="#FF005C9C" />
            <!--<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="2" Height="100" Margin="0,-100,0,0"  FontSize="48" Style="{StaticResource NumUpDownButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, ConverterParameter=Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.IncreaseReturnCommand, ElementName=lvItems}" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Height="100"  FontSize="48" Style="{StaticResource NumUpDownButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, ConverterParameter=Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DecreaseReturnCommand, ElementName=lvItems}" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="3" Height="100" Margin="0,-100,0,0"  FontSize="48" Style="{StaticResource NumUpDownButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, ConverterParameter=Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.IncreaseMildewCommand, ElementName=lvItems}" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Height="100"  FontSize="48" Style="{StaticResource NumUpDownButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, ConverterParameter=Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DecreaseMildewCommand, ElementName=lvItems}" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="4" Height="100" Margin="0,-100,0,0"  FontSize="48" Style="{StaticResource NumUpDownButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, ConverterParameter=Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.IncreaseCreditCommand, ElementName=lvItems}" Opacity="0.9"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Height="100"  FontSize="48" Style="{StaticResource NumUpDownButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, ConverterParameter=Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectionConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DecreaseCreditCommand, ElementName=lvItems}" Opacity="0.9"/>-->  
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ReturnDataListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="listViewItemPresenter" d:DesignWidth="938.908" d:DesignHeight="103.083"
                        ContentMargin="0" 
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Padding="0" 
                        PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1" 
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="False" 
                        SelectedBorderThickness="0" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                        Margin="15,0,0,0" 
                        SelectedForeground="Black" 
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="{StaticResource OrangeBackground}" 
                        SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{StaticResource OrangeBackground}" 
                        SelectedBackground="{StaticResource OrangeBackground}" 
                        DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
                        Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" 
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                        PlaceholderBackground="{StaticResource BackgroundGray}">
                    </ListViewItemPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!--<Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ReturnDataTemplate}"/>-->
    </Style>
```

In the Code behind of the XAML Page, I added the behavior of the ScrollViewer:

```
private void lvItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         SetScrollViewer();
    }

private async void SetScrollViewer()
    {
        if (lvItems.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var item = lvItems.SelectedItem;

        var listViewItem = (FrameworkElement)lvItems.ContainerFromItem(item);

        if (listViewItem == null)
        {
            lvItems.ScrollIntoView(item);
        }

        while (listViewItem == null)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
            listViewItem = (FrameworkElement)lvItems.ContainerFromItem(item);
        }


        var topLeft =
            listViewItem
                .TransformToVisual(lvItems)
                .TransformPoint(new Point()).Y;
        var lvih = listViewItem.ActualHeight;
        var lvh = lvItems.ActualHeight;
        var desiredTopLeft = (lvh - lvih) / 2.0;
        var desiredDelta = topLeft - desiredTopLeft;

        // Calculations relative to the ScrollViewer within the ListView
        var scrollViewer = lvItems.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        var currentOffset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        var desiredOffset = currentOffset + desiredDelta;
        //scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(desiredOffset);

        // better yet if building for Windows 8.1 to make the scrolling smoother use:
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, desiredOffset, null);
    }
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Hy Sybren, i added some code fragments., Thanks

Comment: You should add the code to your OP and not post it as an answer.

Comment: @J.Fammler Its better to upload code at Dropbox and share the link than posting big codes.